# what happend After system.gc?

Tags: java

Suppose I have class A and **in class A** I make an objects of class B and C . after of little time  the object of class A that maked befor it is null . what happened after *System.gc()* on objects b and c of class B and C? is it ready for wiping ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on how garbage collection works? Basically there are two things to remember: 1) if there is no way to navigate from any live thread to an object in question it is elligible for collection (in your case, if the `A` instance is the only one holding a strong reference to the instances of `B` and `C` then if there aren't any references to that `A` instances anymore, all 3 of them are elligible for collection). 2) There is no guarantee if and when elligible objects are a actually collected (thus you can't know the situation after `System.gc()` for sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you have an instance `A` that refers to instances `B` and `C` (of any class), in this fashion:

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
```

If `A` is unreachable, and `B` and `C` are reachable only through `A`, the whole object graph is eligible for GC.

Comment: Note : If the same `B` is used in two distinct `A`, both `A` need to be "nullified" for this `B` to be eligible for GC

Comment: @AxelH Yeah, clarified that a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If there is no another reference on your program that contain the address of theses objects A, B and C, after calling System.gc(), the space allocated to these objects on memory will be freed.